# can we search our own +1s?

Tags: google-plus-1

Sometimes I would have +1-ed something really useful. And at a later time I want to get back to it. I tried to type my search term in the search bar, but Google+ currently does not show up anything.

Is there anyway you can search through your +1s and find stuff you want?

Answer (score 4):

For a list of your +1-ed sites.

`https://plus.google.com/me/plusones`

And if you want to get them in a JSON-like format that can be parsed.

`https://plus.google.com/_/plusone/get?oid=<google-plus-id>`

Comment: @deostroll, Do mark the answer as accepted if you find it suitable. Cheers! :)